# Is gravitational redshift reversible?

Tags: general-relativity, reversibility, gravitational-redshift

Imagine a scenario where a LASER beam is shot from the surface of one planet to a detector on another.  Assume there are no atmosphere and nothing affects the beam in any way between the planets.  Assume the planets are identical masses and densities (same radius).  It would seem to me that the beam would gravitationally redshift when it left the emitter on the first planet and then blueshift back to the exact original color when it reached the detector on the second planet.  If it did not, it would seem to be a violation of conservation of energy.  Can this be proven mathematically?

Comment: Energy is not conserved (not even well defined) in GR. It is believed that the red shift due to space expansion is one example of energy non conservation. Your example about redshirt in gravitational fields conserves energy though.

Comment: "*the beam would gravitationally redshift when it left the emitter on the first planet and then blueshift back*" - This is a consequence of measuring the energy (color) of light in different frames of reference, because energy is frame dependent. When you measure consistently always in the same frame, energy in the Schwarzschild spacetime is conserved. This means that the beam never redshifts or blueshifts in the same coordinates. For example, in the Schwarzschild coordinates, there is no gravitational redshift. The energy (color) of a photon, whether ascending or descending, never changes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, given a Schwarzschild metric (or any metric satisfying the equivalence principle), you can derive the gravitational redshift or blueshift of a photon traveling from one place to another, and you will find that it is reversible.

If you like, you can think of gravitational redshift as caused by gravitational time dilation. For symmetric detector/emitters on symmetric planets, both will have the same time dilation relative to infinity and clocks at both will have the same ticks, so the exact same color will be achieved.

For the Schwarzschild metric, time dilation and redshift are given by $\frac{1}{1+z} = \frac{t_{0}}{t_{\infty}} = \sqrt{1-\frac{r_{s}}{r}}$, which is only a function of position.

Comment: Thanks, and I had thought so, as I don't see how else it would work with conservation of energy.  What I was looking for here is the mathematics though.

Comment: What mathematics are you looking for? If I write down a metric that is identically equal to itself, it is trivially proven.